# Three dots in Swift init method

Tags: swift, init, combine

I was looking at some Apple Combine source code and saw a Publisher name `MergeMany` with an init method defined like this:

```swift
public init(_ upstream: Upstream...)
```

What are the three dots `...` after the `Upstream`? The value of `Upstream` is just another publisher as defined in the Struct definition.

```swift
public struct MergeMany<Upstream> : Publisher where Upstream : Publisher {
```

Comment: This is a "[variadic parameter](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html#ID171)".

Answer (score 6):

The three dots mean that it is a variadic function and can take a list of `Upstream`. This is a function of the Swift Language and not the Combine Framework.

From Sergio Pietri's [Blogpost](https://medium.com/@SergioPietri/what-are-variadic-functions-in-c-6205e26c729f):

> Why should we use variadic functions? When you declare this type of function you are adding flexibility to the code. For example: the printf is probably the most notable function that uses this principle. The printf will take N amount of arguments and has many different parameters to format the output it will print.

And from the Swift [documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html):

> A variadic parameter accepts zero or more values of a specified type. You use a variadic parameter to specify that the parameter can be passed a varying number of input values when the function is called. Write variadic parameters by inserting three period characters (...) after the parameter’s type name.
> The values passed to a variadic parameter are made available within the function’s body as an array of the appropriate type. For example, a variadic parameter with a name of numbers and a type of Double... is made available within the function’s body as a constant array called numbers of type [Double].

Comment: Interesting. Is there a reason one would choose a variadic parameter over just an array in the definition?

Comment: Updated answer to answer your question.